# SpringBoot + Thymeleaf + Bootstrap Carousel not rotating between pictures nor carousel controls working

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, carousel, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot + Thymeleaf + Bootstrap web application and I have a Bootstrap Carousel on the main page. The carousel works fine when I load it statically but when I have it running in the SpringBoot/Thymeleaf environment it doesn't rotate between the images nor do the left/right controls work.

**HTML/Thymeleaf:**

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes,width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" data-th-src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" data-th-href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../static/css/main.css" data-th-href="@{/css/main.css}" />
<!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-th-src="@{/webjars/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>

<div id="pictureCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000" data-pause="null" style="width:100%;height:auto;margin:auto;background-size:contain;display: block;">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#pictureCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#pictureCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#pictureCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="../static/images/pic1" th:src="@{/images/pic1}" alt="Pic1" style="width:100%;height: 500px;"></img>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Pic1</p>
            </div> <!--height="396.5px" width="1024px"> -->
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="../static/images/pic2" th:src="@{/images/pic2}" alt="Pic2" style="width:100%;height: 500px;"></img><!--height="396.5px" width="1024px"> -->
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Pic2</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="../static/images/pic3" th:src="@{/images/pic3}" alt="pic3" style="width:100%;height: 500px;"></img> <!--height="396.5px" width="1024px"> -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#pictureCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#pictureCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is interesting. Cannot reproduce it without Thymeleaf. Even without images the Carousel works: [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLxRbE).